# LARAVEL how access mariaDB SQL Server on DBF tables

Tags: php, laravel, orm, mariadb, dbf

I found a way to access FoxPro tables with MariaDB Server using ENGINE=CONNECT.

Through MySQL WorkBench I can insert, update, delete rows on existing DBF tables.

Following tutorial https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart with that configuration for the App, it works because I can insert rows in the `tasks` table, but the page doesn't show the column `name` value.

Trying do delete a row i get the error:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:.
```

Is there someone knows restrictions or rules on Laravel using tables for that configuration.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit to use Markdown formatting.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)) / What do you expect? / What error do you get? **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: Hopefully make it a bit more readable

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong `HTTP` method. In a RESTful API, usually you need to set the request method to `DELETE`, not `GET` or `POST`. Not sure how laravel does it but the error message says whatever you sent is an invalid argument due to the wrong HTTP method being used.

Also, try not to use reserved keywords for your column names, it can cause problems and you'll need to backtick the ` the column name in your queries.

Check out the list of reserved keywords here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Check your routing configuration and check which method is configured for your delete endpoint.